# Is it possible to remove my default gateway from /etc/resolv.conf after successful VPN connection?

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, pptp

I have configured PPTP VPN connection on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS via NetworkManager (nm-pptp-ppp-plugin) and it works. My configuration:

1. *VPN*

   - *Gateway*
   - *User name*
   - *Password*
   - *Advanced* - set some options on *PPTP Advanced Options*
2. *IPv4 Settings*

   - *Method*: *Automatic (VPN) addresses only*
   - *DNS servers* : 192.168.1.1 (internal IP address of VPN's default gateway)
3. *IPv6 Settins*

   - *Method*: *Ignore*

I commented out `#dns=dnsmasq` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` and `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Without VPN connection my `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the following line:

```
nameserver 192.168.3.1
```

where 192.168.3.1 is IP of my router.
After that, VPN connection `/etc/resolv.conf` changes to:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.3.1
```

But as far as I can understand it should contain only 192.168.1.1.

Is it possible to remove my router's IP (192.168.3.1) from `/etc/resolv.conf` programmatically?
I mean by [NetworkManager dispatcher](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Network_services_with_NetworkManager_dispatcher) or similar.

It seems that I do not have the [DNS leak issue](https://dnsleaktest.com) with my current configuration.

P.S. I understand that my question may have been discussed before, but possible duplicates do not fit my needs.

**Update 1.** On my other 16.04 laptop I also needed to disable `systemd-resolved.service` with:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: This is a well known bug of NM. Very hard to overcome and yes, DNS leak may occur. This has been fixed in Ubuntu 17.04 so you might consider upgrading the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2** 
I wrote simple straightforward dirty dispatcher and placed it in
`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/03vpn`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
RESOLV_CONF=`readlink /etc/resolv.conf`
ROUTER_IP="nameserver 192.168.3.1"

logger -t DNS-antileak "start"
# disable local router IP in /etc/resolv.conf
if [ "$2" = "vpn-up" ]; then
    sed -i "s/$ROUTER_IP/#$ROUTER_IP/g" $RESOLV_CONF
    logger -t DNS-antileak "disabled $ROUTER_IP on vpn-up"
fi 

if [ "$2" = "vpn-down" ]; then
   sed -i "s/#$ROUTER_IP/$ROUTER_IP/g" $RESOLV_CONF
    logger -t DNS-antileak "enabled $ROUTER_IP on vpn-down"
fi 
logger -t DNS-antileak "end"

exit 0
```

It may be activated with

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/03vpn
sudo chmod 755 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/03vpn
```

I tested it with OpenVPN and PPTP connections.

Also I found other DNS-leak tests: [Whoer](https://whoer.net/) and [WhatLeaks](https://whatleaks.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known bug of NetworkManager, specifically it is [#1211110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1211110). It goes back to Ubuntu 13.04 up to 16.04 and *to a worse extent* to Ubuntu 16.10.

> It seems that I do not have DNS leak issue with my current configuration.

Then consider yourself pretty lucky. :) Most users (including myself) experienced severe DNS leaks and tried different approaches to solve them.

Here are some approaches suggested in the bug report (summarized):

#### Comment #22 by Mac Bassett

> Make a backup copy of this NetworkManager file:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper.orig
> ```
>
> Add the following 3 lines to the file.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf $@
> /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper.orig $@
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper
> ```
>
> Caveat: you need to run the following command after disconnecting the VPN.
>
> ```
> sudo script_type=down dev=tun0 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
> ```

#### Comments #27 and #29 by myself

> Edit your VPN connection (via NM) and set up static DNS, for example using Google servers:
>
> ```
> 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
> ```
>
> This way, the DNS request is sent through an external IP, hence it is routed using the VPN.
>
> Then also set up your wireless connection to use those static DNS servers.

#### Comment #31 by DaveHenson

> Run `openvpn` through the command line.

---

*(... some other cumbersome solutions that I won't discuss here ...)*

---

#### Comment #81 by Çağatay Yüksel

> Remove this configuration file:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> Add this line to the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:
>
> ```
> dns=dnsmasq
> ```
>
> If you have the `dnsmasq` package installed, you should make sure the `dnsmasq` service is not enabled otherwise this will not work. You should also reboot.

## The real solution

This bug [has been fixed in Ubuntu 17.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317/comments/82). Rather than trying random patches on your system, it is probably a better idea to simply upgrade. :)

Comment: Thank you for information, Andrea. I wrote simple dispatcher for paranoidal persons :) See **update 2** above.