# How can I prevent DNS leakage when using a VPN in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, openvpn, dnsmasq

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. I want to ensure that my DNS requests use my VPN DNS rather than my ISP DNS.

In 16.04, preventing DNS leakage was easy: just disable the dnsmasq entry in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.

However, in 18.04, there is no dnsmasq entry in the above file. I have tried modifying the .ovpn file with:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

This supposedly modifies the /etc/resolv.conf file to use the VPN DNS but it doesn't work. resolv.conf just shows: nameserver 127.0.0.53 irrespective of whether I am using the VPN. It should show the IP of the VPN DNS servers.

Does anyone know how to prevent DNS leakage in 18.04 (whether or not dnsmasq is the issue)? Thanks.

Comment: At first you should check DNS leakage with one of the services - [dnsleaktest.com](https://dnsleaktest.com/) or [whatleaks.com](https://whatleaks.com/). For 16.04 LTS I have [anti-leak dispatcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/943166/66509) for NetworkManager, I'm not sure if it works on 18.04 LTS.