# How do I install the latest network-manager on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

Due to a [bug 1211110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1211110) in `network-manager`, I need to update it to a latest version to [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317/comments/82) it.

What is the best way for me to do so?

Comment: FIY on 16.04 LTS I fix DNS leak by [Network Manager dispatcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/943166/66509). Is it your goal?

Comment: @N0rbert My goal is to fix the possity of a DNS leak in the most reliable way possible. I'd like to make sure that there's no system-provided solution before applying patches like that. (Is upgrading to the next LTS the best solution, really? What's the meaning of "5 years of support" for LTS, then?) Were I to apply the patch you kindly provided, I would like to understand how it works, first.

Comment: @N0rbert 1. I'm supposed to manually specify ROUTER_IP which will get excluded from resolv.conf. Can I really be sure it will stay the same and not change at some point in the future?

2. `sed` edits the resolv.conf file, but at which point does the configuration get applied?

Comment: Configuration is applied twice: on *vpn-up* (disable router IP) and *vpn-down* (enable router IP) events. It is very likely that other methods exist, but I use my method. You may want try method from [Comment 92 for bug 1211110](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1211110/comments/92). I did not find it before.

Comment: @N0rbert But what reads the resolv.conf file the instant you write it and applies the configuration?

Comment: It is dispatcher for NetworkManager. So all actions are made by NetworkManager internals.

Comment: @N0rbert You mean NetworkManager should reread resolv.conf after the dispatcher completes? What if my ROUTER_IP changes?

Comment: Yes. And if your ROUTER_IP changes you should edit dispatcher file and specify new address. I use this script on stationary desktop systems, so my router IP does not change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove my default gateway from /etc/resolv.conf after successful PPTP VPN connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943008/is-it-possible-to-remove-my-default-gateway-from-etc-resolv-conf-after-successf)